# How to set AWS API Gateway timeout value for Lambda Integration using AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have an AWS lambda gateway, with lambda function integration, defined in AWS CDK. I want to explicitly set API Gateway's timeout for a particular method's lambda, and could not find a way to do so in the official documentation. I checked:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-apigateway-readme.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.LambdaIntegration.html

Comment: Do you mean set the timeout value for a Lambda function?

Comment: No, not for the lambda function. I mean for the API Gateway itself. See Integration Timeout here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`LambdaIntegration`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.LambdaIntegration.html) has a [`LambdaIntegrationOptions`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.LambdaIntegrationOptions.html) and that has a [`timeout`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.LambdaIntegrationOptions.html#timeout):

> The maximum amount of time an integration will run before it returns without a response.
> Must be between 50 milliseconds and 29 seconds.